# Office 365 and SharePoint list events

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, office365

This is my first encounter with Office 365. I have made customization to SharePoint before (C#), but never to a hosted SharePoint.

My problem is rather simple:

I have a task list in SharePoint. Every time the task list is updated, I would like to send the data to an external service.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Is it possible to register my own assembly with SharePoint or is SharePoint Apps the only option with a hosted SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your own solution as long as it's sandboxed. Sandboxing has been deprecated in SP 2013 so going down the route of using the new App model is probably the best thing to do. Sandboxing would probably also prevent you from talking to an external service.

I would do an auto-hosted app and use a remote event receiver. Auto-hosting a quick to setup but requires Azure. If you can't use Azure, a provider hosted app would be your next choice.

More info about remote event receivers here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220048.aspx.